Obtaining corr matrix (probit residual correlations) for observed variables after fitting an EFA model using lavaan
Looks like lavaan's efa() function does not have an option to generate the correlation matrix for observed variables. I wonder how can I obtain the corr matrix (probit residual correlations) for ordered observed variables for which the WLSMV estimator is declared.
#EFA 
Precarity_efa <- efa(data = RADx0030_Imputed_imp1, ov.names = c("CHALLIVE", "CHALFOOD", "CHALWATER", "CHALTRANS", "CHALHLTH", "CHALMEDS"), estimator="WLSMV", ordered = TRUE,
           nfactors = 1:2, rotation = "geomin")

summary(Precarity_efa,nd = 3L, alpha.level = 0.05,
lambda = TRUE, theta = TRUE, psi = TRUE, fit.table = TRUE,
fs.determinacy = FALSE, eigenvalues = TRUE, sumsq.table = TRUE,
lambda.structure = FALSE, se = FALSE, zstat = FALSE)



Looks like lavaan's efa() function does not have an option to generate the correlation matrix for observed variables

What makes it look like that?  Check the ?lavInspect help page for the vast amount of information that can be extracted from a fitted lavaan object.
Edit: Need to specify the argument output = "lavaan" to request a lavaan-class object
Precarity_efa <- efa(data = RADx0030_Imputed_imp1,
                     ov.names = c("CHALLIVE", "CHALFOOD", 
                                  "CHALWATER", "CHALTRANS",
                                  "CHALHLTH", "CHALMEDS"),
                     ordered = TRUE, output = "lavaan",
                     nfactors = 1:2, rotation = "geomin")

Here is how you can get the unrestricted polychoric correlation matrix, which does not assume a factor-model (equivalent to a multivariate intercept-only (cumulative) probit model):
lavInspect(Precarity_efa, "sampstat")

And the (factor-)model-implied polychoric correlation matrix, calculated as a function of EFA parameters:
lavInspect(Precarity_efa, "cor.ov")

Neither would be "residual" (partial) correlations, given the factors.  Those would simply be found in the standardized matrix of residuals (Theta):
lavInspect(Precarity_efa, "std")$theta

But correlations will all be 0 by default in an EFA model.  You would have to free them in model syntax using efa()* blocks to run an EFA as a more general (E)SEM.

Thanks! Your suggested codes returned below errors. Also, could you clarify the differences between the unrestricted polychoric correlation matrix and  the model-implied polychoric correlation matrix. Error in UseMethod("lavInspect", object) :
no applicable method for 'lavInspect' applied to an object of class "c('efaList', 'list')"

I edited my answer to add the output = "lavaan" required for the lavInspect() function to work.  You can read details about factor models for categorical data here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3162326/
